# Can I run my jupyter notebook that contains seaborn code on GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, cuda, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I have CUDA compatible GPU (Nvidia GeForce 1060) in my system. While analyzing a bigger dataset, I often have to use pair plot function of the seaborn library, it consumes a lot of time. Is there a way I can run my entire notebook on GPU. I mean, apart from seaborn, I want to run all of my code on GPU, is it possible?

I have watched a couple of videos on youtube that advises using numba python compiler and jit annotations, I want to know whether there is a generic setting that can be applied to to the anaconda framework so that, whatever I run on anaconda should utilize GPU.

I am aware that tensorflow and keras can be run on GPU.

Comment: no there is no general way to run "all of my code on GPU".  It is not possible, whether in a Jupyter notebook, or Anaconda, or any other setting.

Comment: Thanks, Robert- this helps!

Comment: Good question chotu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I can run my entire notebook on GPU. I mean, apart from seaborn, I want to run all of my code on GPU, is it possible?

In a word, no there is not. There is no way to run generic Python code or libraries on the GPU.

> I am aware that `tensorflow` and `keras` can be run on GPU.

Neither tensorflow nor keras can be "run on" a GPU. They can accelerate parts of their computations with GPUs, but that process doesn't involve running a single line of Python on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you totally can!  But just not with seaborn.

You can use the [RAPIDS library and ecosystem](https://rapids.ai/index.html) (cudf and the GPU accelerated visualization library cuxfilter, with its connections to holoviews, datashader, and plot.ly dash api).  Here is a great quick start guide to cuxfilter: https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuxfilter/stable/10%20minutes%20to%20cuxfilter.html

Here is a blog of cuxfilter with dash api: https://medium.com/rapids-ai/plotly-census-viz-dashboard-powered-by-rapids-1503b3506652

We're about to do a tutorial at JupyterCon this week, if you have time to see it.
https://cfp.jupytercon.com/2020/schedule/presentation/242/using-rapids-and-jupyter-to-accelerate-visualization-workflows/

Comment: "I want to know whether there is a generic setting that can be applied to to the anaconda framework so that, whatever I run on anaconda should utilize GPU."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your GPU is supported but there is now (Q3 2020) options to do data manipulation on GPU using libraries such as [cudf](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf) or [cupy](https://cupy.dev/).

I am just starting down this path and from little I've seen, you will have to do some "extra" work in transferring results to a format that Seaborn can handle, but calculations with cudf (and I assume cupy) are much faster (I've seen 5x to 25x improvements so far, and read of even more extreme cases).

You will have to write a little more code though...